# How to convert a regular expression to a String literal and back again?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I:

1. Convert a JavaScript RegExp with flags to a String literal (think JSON),
2. And convert that literal back to a regex?

For example with the String `"the weather is nice today"`:

```
var myRe = new RegExp("weather","gi");
var myReToString = myRe.toString(); // myReToString is now "/weather/gi"

var myReCopy = /* How to get this copy only from myReToString ? */
```

---

To modify the original RegExp properties see [torazaburo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38160886/4174897).

Comment: My I ask what is the use case for converting regex to string and back again?

Comment: Your `.replace()` method would break any regex that contained a forward slash in the actual expression. Also, your technique assumes the `gi` flags should always be used.

Comment: `eval` would do it.

Comment: Related: [Serialization of RegExp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075927/serialization-of-regexp), [Can I store RegExp and Function in JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328119/can-i-store-regexp-and-function-in-json)

Comment: @SWLim: I wanted to 'extend'/add to the regex, to something like this: "weather | is "

Comment: @kyll: go ahead, I can only learn, you can delete our two comments if you can too

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, the gi flags are just an example

Comment: Done. Let me know what you think. Also, feel free to [edit] your post some more or rollback my changes if you don't like them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the accessor properties on the `RegExp` prototype such as `source` and `flags`. So you can do:

```
var myRe = new RegExp("weather", "gi")

var copyRe = new RegExp(myRe.source, myRe.flags);
```

For the spec see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.flags.

#### Serializing and deserializing regexps

If your intent in doing this is to serialize the regexp, such as into JSON, and then deserialize it back, I would recommend storing the regexp as a tuple of `[source, flags]`, and then reconstituting it using `new RexExp(source, flags)`.  That seems slightly cleaner than trying to pick it apart using regexp or eval'ing it. For instance, you could stringify it as

```
function stringifyWithRegexp(o) {
  return JSON.stringify(o, function replacer(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof RegExp) return [value.source, value.flags];
    return value;
  });
}
```

On the way back you can use `JSON.parse` with a reviver to get back the regexp.

#### Modifying regexps

If you want to modify a regexp while retaining the flags, you can create a new regexp with modified source and the same flags:

```
var re = /weather/gim;
var newre = new RegExp(re.source + "| is", re.flags);
```

Comment: The whole point is that you don't have access to the original regex.

Comment: *"and back again?"* means from a string. The output of step 1 is the input of step 2.

Comment: hence the question to OP of why he/she needs to do this. Perhaps there's something better that can solve the root problem :)

Comment: Actually you answer what I meant to ask, thanks @SWLim for asking to clarify. Because the direct answer to the question is eval, I accepted it for the answer, however yours did actually solve my problem, this mentioned your answer in the edit

Comment: No problem. Just a word of caution, I'd avoid eval (Google 'javascript evil eval' and you'll see many articles on it), but it should be fine as long as [you know what you're dealing with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to get back the regular expression:

```
var myRe = RegExp("weather", "gi");
var myReString = myRe.toString();
eval(myReString); // => /weather/gi
```

NOTE: [`eval` can execute arbitrary javascript expression.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!) Use `eval` only if you're sure the string is generated from regular expression `toString` method.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this code works in all cases, but I'm sure that this can be done using regex:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('^/(.+)/(.*)$')
function stringToRegex(s) {
    var match = s.match(regex)
    return new RegExp(match[1], match[2])
}

var test = new RegExp("weather", "gi")

console.log(stringToRegex(test.toString()))
console.log(stringToRegex(test.toString()).toString() === test.toString())
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-LkTbruEE5ohImzF)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work in all cases, because the `.+` is greedy. The second `/` will only match the last one in the string.