# Create RegExp from regex formatted string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, ember.js

I’m sending a regex expression via JSON from my Ember front end to my Node server. When the regex expression is sent it is converted to a string. This is an example of what node receives:

```
{"find":{"name":"/^sp101/"},"sort":{"name":"1"},"limit":5}
```

In this example how do I convert find[‘name’] from a string to a regex? i.e. I want to extract /^sp101/ from find[‘name’] instead of “/^sp101/“

When I pass the string "/^sp101/" to a RegExp constructor it converts it to //^sp19// which I do not want.

Is there a way to accomplish this without using string manipulation? i.e. slicing off the first and last "/" before passing it to the constructor.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160746/how-to-convert-a-regular-expression-to-a-string-literal-and-back-again

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`

```
var s = "/^sp101/"

eval(s) -> returns /^sp101/
```