# Unexpected token / in JSON. How to include a regex in an array in a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I want to include a regex in an array in JSON, like this:

```
"routes:before": {
    "./middleware/foo": {
        "enabled": false,
        "paths": [/^\/(?!css|js|img).+$/ig] // <== doesn't work, throws
    }
},
```

But it throws:

> SyntaxError: \middleware.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 884

Although [they say](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-middleware.html#middleware-configuration-properties) it is possible:

> In addition to a literal string, route can be a path matching pattern, a regular expression, or an array including all these types.

What do I miss? How to pass a regex in an array in JSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I store RegExp and Function in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328119/can-i-store-regexp-and-function-in-json)

Comment: So the first answer on the question from which I marked yours question a duplicate says `Store RegExp pattern as a string` and that doesn't solve your problem? `"paths": ["/^\/(?!css|js|img).+$/ig"]`

Comment: JSON does not know RegExp, JSON does only know `string`,  `number`, 
 `object`, `array`, `true`, `false` and `null`, as values.

Comment: JSON can't contain RegExp. Path can be regular expression. You can check the *Route paths* section of express routing documentation (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) to see some examples of using RexExp for path.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to store it as a `string`, i.e. `"paths": "[/^\/(?!css|js|img).+$/ig]"`

Then, you can reconstruct: `var re = new RegExp(paths, 'i');`

JSON allows `strings`, `booleans`, `numbers`, `objects`, `arrays`, and `null`. You cannot store/transfer a regular expression unless it is as a `string`.

Comment: So you've basically copied the comments to an answer? Also your `i.e.` code is incorrect. You should provide some documentation and an excerpt from the documentation at least.

Comment: What is incorrect about it? And no, it was not a copy from the comments.

Comment: It's supposed to be an array. If the user tried to use the string you have as a regex they'd get a set of "any of the following characters": `/^(?!cs|jimg).+$` (literally)