# Storing Regex value in Cypress config

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

How can I store Regex value in cypress config file?
I'm using the following regex in the test:

```
cy.get('.company_highlight').contains(/JPM|Morgan/g)
```

When I put this value in the config file I have to store it as string, but then the test will fail since its a string value.

I tried directl inputting that value into config file:

#### `cypress.json`

```
{
   "Company":/JPM|Morgan/g
}
```

And in the test:

```
cy.get('.company_highlight').contains(Cypress.config().Company)
```

Which gives error:
`Unexpected token / in JSON`

Comment: Regex literals aren't supported in JSON. You'd have to store it in the JSON as a *string*, with appropriate escapes, then create a `new RegExp` from it per https://stackoverflow.com/q/874709/3001761. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8328119/3001761.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) doesn't support regex literals like you'd write it in JavaScript. And string values have to be wrapped in double quotes.

I can imagine you can still use what JavaScript has to offer when it comes to [regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
let re = new RegExp(Cypress.config().Company, 'g')
```

and the json file:

```json
{
   "Company": "(JPM|Morgan)"
}
```